# Is this possible with the Navigation Controller?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I'm using the navigation controller project. I'd like to have a main menu without the Navigation Controller bar. But other screens SHOULD have the navigation bar.

I did this by setting the viewDidLoad in my RootViewController to:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
```

And inside viewDidLoad in my childController to:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
```

and that's ok, but when I click on the button in the main menu that transitions
to this child (i.e., child = another screen with a different xib). I'd like the child's navigationBar to animate to the left, as do the rest of the elements on the child window. But the navigation bar just appears. I also tried to set the navigationBarHidden to NO in the child, once I instantiate it from the rootviewcontroller (i.e., my main menu) but that doesn't work either.

Which leads me to conclude that a navigationBar cannot be animated, i.e., there's
just ONE navigationBar on the screen. If that's the case, then to get the functionality
I want I'd have to create my own type of view transitioning using Core Animation,
am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```